# Error while updating composer

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to update composer in my Symfony project and I'm getting this error:
[image]

[image]

PHP Version: 5.5.12

Comment: Is there a duplicate sentence in composer.json ? If not please update your question with the content of that file

Comment: I update my question and I delete duplicate in composer.json .. you can help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php -d memory_limit=-1 composer update

or

set memory size in php.ini to -1 (not recommended on a shared hosting)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this command:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer update
```

See if that works?
This was from the link in the error message output here:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors

Comment: Have you also tried `composer self-update` command? Maybe your version is out of date?